# Why whole rxjs is imported on a feature angular module

Tags: angular, rxjs, bundle

I'm analyzing my angular app bundle, I can't understand why rxjs is imported on one feature module `1.b6e2bed6d2a2d3892bd9.chunk.js`, all what I import in that module is like below:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

[image: webpack-bundle-analyzer]

How to find out why whole rxjs is imported on that module?

Comment: you should use **tree shaking** https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: I'm running prod build with angular cli! `ng build --prod --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json`

Comment: You might want to try to add a `--build-optimizer` flag for better results (takes a bit longer though).

Comment: I'm getting similar result with `--build-optimizer`

Comment: If it is imported like `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'` in feature module, it cannot be imported entirely. Seek the problem somewhere else. The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and thus the problem cannot be reproduced or analyzed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
I found the source of problem, I'm importing customHttpProvider on that module, I guess `ng-jhipster` package pull the whole `rxjs` library

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { JhiInterceptableHttp } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { AuthExpiredInterceptor } from './auth-expired.interceptor';
import { ErrorHandlerInterceptor } from './errorhandler.interceptor';
import { NotificationInterceptor } from './notification.interceptor';

export function interceptableFactory(
    backend: XHRBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    injector: Injector
    //stateStorageService: StateStorageService,
    //eventManager: EventManager
) {
    return new JhiInterceptableHttp(
        backend,
        defaultOptions,
        [
            new AuthExpiredInterceptor(injector
              //, stateStorageService
            ),
            // Other interceptors can be added here
            new ErrorHandlerInterceptor(
              //eventManager
            ),
            new NotificationInterceptor()
        ]
    );
};

export function customHttpProvider() {
    return {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: interceptableFactory,
        deps: [
            XHRBackend,
            RequestOptions,
            Injector,
            //StateStorageService,
            //EventManager
        ]
    };
};
```